# Jquery dynamic Content impacting all users

Tags: jquery, spring-boot

I am creating pages using dynamic jquery like below. When I deploy code on server, when one user searches something and results display, other logged in user in different machines are getting same results.

Code sample,

```
(‘#content’).append(‘<input type=‘text’>’);
```

I am using above code inside Document.ready(). When one user types something on text box other user gets same thing automatically typed.

Comment: I think it would be useful if we knew how this page is served to your users, and the technology you are using. It looks like it would be normal if client pages are synchonized to the same component which is built server-side, like it can be done in NodeJs iirc

Comment: I am using web service Spring boot to get JSON string and using dynamic Jquery to display JSON String UI.

Comment: @Kaddath How can we avoid that, its like multiuser application. For example we have search box and if one user types something in search box other logged in user getting same search string typed on there UI!!!

Comment: I know nothing about Spring boot, sorry. I recommend you add details to your post so that people can help you more accurately, like how your page is constructed/served to your users

Comment: Thank you @Kaddath. Forget about Spring boot that will give you just JSON data. Problem is on Jquery UI where I am showing Data by constructing elements dynamically like above. Let me know your thiughts